# convert typescript interface structure to react proptypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, react-proptypes

I have a dummy project with react and type script.in my project i used typescript interface and react proptypes together.but i have a problem.i can't convert my interfaces to proptypes.

this my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; 

interface IMyComponent1 {
    type: 'type1';
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    items?: [
        { name: string, id: string, url: string, badge: { title: string, color: string } }
    ]
}

interface IMyComponent2 {
    type: 'type2';
    id?: string;
    question?: string;
    answer?: string;
}

type IMyComponent = IMyComponent1 | IMyComponent2;

const MyComponent: React.FC<IMyComponent> = props => {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {

};

export default MyComponent;
```

can any one help me for create react proptypes according to IMyComponent interface.

Comment: This cannot be done because types cannot generate values. But values always generate types and these types can be obtained via the `typeof` operator. Start with a proptypes object.

Comment: Have you tried something like https://github.com/danReynolds/typescript-proptypes-generator ???